# Movie about attacking Roots/Giant Plant?

Tags: story-identification

Last night, as I went to turn off the internet, on my mum's TV there was a movie/series (the last of a regular commercial break as I watched, it may be an indication it was a movie). My mum was asleep and I couldn't find her remote without waking her up so I could see what the title was in the info box.

The first scene I saw there was this couple at a fence and the guy is trying to climb over to reach the girl, at the same time there's an earthquake and giant roots are coming up from the ground, but then it stops as the roots retreat and the couple seem surprised. The scene then jumps to this time with a garden and this old man is saying about how his garden repelled the roots but had to prepared because other will find out about this.

The next scene was in a car, a woman (who later I believe is identified as Dr Stein) and a Government Official, he asks Dr Stein if there is a clue in the bible or the Dead Sea Scrolls that will lead them to a solutions, Dr Stein says that the "Seeds came from Eden" and recites something (from the bible?) that something would clear the corruption of the world which leads the government official to believe that they can't defeat these roots with weapons as they seems to have grown and need another angle to stop them. this seems to imply

- someone discovered where Eden is located
- some seeds was taken from there must have broken containment (obviously)
- the Government has tried to stop the roots with destructive force

The car pulls up to a military jeep, a satellite image of the area shows the root's progression and Dr Stein notices a isolated area which the roots don't touch despite having destroyed everything so far (as if avoiding this area). As Dr Stein and the government official go to ask for transport their driver says they are going to miss there as Reno has been destroyed and the Presidential Cabinet is being evacuated to a shelter in the mountains.

The final scene I saw (because it was late at night and I needed to get to bed for work) had the couple I mentioned earlier, they find an opened facility (probably looking for shelter or supplies) but before they go they notice a man out front who is armed. Something snaps which causes the man to take out his gun (seems to be a rifle) and the couple run however the man chases after them shooting which the couple question (since if he was just guarding from intruders why pursue? I assume it's because facility was holding some secret and he had orders to kill anyone any potential witnesses without question)

Comment: You went to turn off the Internet? Please don't.

Comment: @MrLister At least Memor-X [didn't drop it](https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/UTBsm0LzSP0?start=142&end=177).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the movie you are talking about is called ["Seeds of Destruction"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706680/) but I'm not entirely sure.

Plot summary:

> Militant environmentalists Kate and Joe witness, and videotape, the rapid growth of a gigantic root system that literally begins mowing through the country like an earthquake. At the same time, government agent Jack Taylor contacts plant expert Jocelyn Snow, who discovers that her ex-colleague, Frame Marcos, is the probable source of the ancient seed that started the whole ecological disaster. Under the growing threat of massive tsunamis should the enormous root system burrow under the ocean, Jack, Jocelyn, Joe and Kate confront Frame in his compound, then return to the place where it all began, with the hopes that Jocelyn can disable the embryonic root and bring the disaster to an end.

Comment: I believe this is the movie. according to the IMDB link it also goes by the name "The Terror Beneath", finding [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJ0L7pGbPVM) i recognize the couple and the old man. [this related video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZiIVHlXeBE) has that same couple and it's titled "Seeds of Destruction"

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the 2009 [*Day of the Triffids*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1332653/) mini-series? I haven't seen this one yet, but it might fit.

(from the IMDB link:):

> It's an up-to-date setting of the 1962 Sci-fi thriller. With the world
>   blinded and the Triffids set loose, it falls upon a band of scattered,
>   sighted survivors to fight this carnivorous plant invasion. With a
>   brave new world of maniacs, warring factions and renegades, the battle
>   on the streets is not only directed at the purple-headed organisms but
>   a battle to survive the sinister street-army headed by megalomaniac
>   Torrence.

Comment: I had to check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Triffids_%282009_TV_series%29) as i saw Day of the Triffids on TV once but didn't know it was a mini series, reading part two it seems when i saw it they combined both parts so i am quite sure it's not Day of the Triffids having seen all of it (unless there is a third part)

Comment: I think you're right, it's probably *Seeds of Destruction*. I haven't seen either one, but the description of *Seeds* looks like a much better fit. I don't know what the downvote was for.